# Error in \title : Overleaf

Tags: errors

I am using Overleaf and am receiving the following error when I try setting the title to my file.

`Illegal parameter number in definition of \@title.
<to be read again> 
                  1`

How should I fix this ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) of your problem. Without one it is nearly impossible to help you.

Comment: Correct the definition of `\@title` so that it no longer uses an illegal parameter number? Usually this means you have `#1` when you want `##1` or `##1` when you want `###1` or `##1` when your want `#1` or `###1` when you want `##1` or ... Or else it means that you've tried to use something like `#1` in a macro which was not defined to absorb any arguments at all. However, that is less likely in this case as it is a standard macro. If you don't think you've redefined it at all, do you have a literal hash symbol in `\title{}` or something?

Comment: @cfr : Yes, I have a hash symbol in my title : `\title{#1}`

Comment: That's the problem, then. Is your paper really titled `#1`? No offence intended: I'm sure there's an audience out there for that kind of thing. Just not my cup of tea, probably.

Comment: @cfr : No, my paper is not just titled #1, there was some text before it in the title but I didn't post it here since I thought the text wasn't relevant to the error.

Comment: Oh. OK. That makes sense. I thought maybe you were confusing trying to change the format of the title with trying to set the content of the title. Just because in the former case, you would have a `#1` and it would be a variable standing in for whatever-the-title-is. I was just confused by the notation. Ignore me ;).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `#` is a special character. TeX assumes you mean to use it to refer to an argument parameter. If you wish to literally typeset a hash symbol, you must escape the character or otherwise request it indirectly.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{A \# to end all \# s}
\author{S. O. M. E. Body}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image: hashes]

Comment: Perfect, that fixed it. I was not aware of # being a special character. Thanks.